# Xcode update stuck on "update"

Tags: ios, xcode, updates

I try to Update my Xcode through the Appstore. Its now 3 hours ago, when I started and its still in status "update". 
I already tried over night and when coming in the morning I got a message, that Xcode could not be download and installed.

So I fear this will never work.

Are there any solutions for this situation. Do I have to uninstall XCode and reinstall from new ? And if yes, how can I do this.

- I have enough space on the disk.

**UPDATE**

After 3 hours I get
"Xcode failed to download"
"Use the Purchases page to try again."

Comment: You can just throw away the xcode.app from you application directory. This should remove Xcode fro you system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I will try this in a hour. Do you mean with throw away -> right button on XCode and "Move to Trash" ? What do you guess how long the update takes normally ?

Comment: Does `Console.app` tell you anything?

Comment: Yes, just move it to the trash. Either by right clicking or je dragging it to the trash. And also check the `Console.app` as @trojanfoe mentioned just to be sure. With my internet connection it takes about 20 min.

Answer (score 1):

Just move to trash Xcode from applications and then reinstall the fresh **Xcode 6/7/7.1** the setup which you have. And for **Xcode 7/7.1** sometimes it works laggy so remove it and install it once again because during installation some of its files could not installed properly.

Comment: I will try. I trashed the App and now its more then 2 hours since I started installing.

Comment: What is your xcode version here ? If it is xcode 7 or higher you should Mac os version 10.10 or 10.10.5 updated Yosemite and it is Xcode 6 then you should left you machine with installation process for full night because i was suffering from this problem and i solved it.

Comment: I had to reset the AppStore. Logout from AppStore. Rebooted the MAC and then started again. After 3 hours it worked then. Very userfriendly system by the way :-)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that your hard drive was full after download finish and start install. So cleared up more space, about 15G when I update to Xcode 7.3.